Render audio from Firebase storage with MediaElementAudioSourceNode
I have a react audio component library (https://github.com/clxrityy/react-audio).
When rendering audio from an external source (such as a firebase storage URL) normal <audio /> component, it works fine.
However, in my <Waveform /> component, where the code has variables like so:
const [analyzerData, setAnalyzerData] = useState<AnalyzerData>();
const [audioCtx, setAudioCtx] = useState<AudioContext>();
const [audioSrc, setAudioSrc] = useState<string>();
const audioElement = useRef<ElementRef<'audio'>>(null);
const sourceNode = useRef<MediaElementAudioSourceNode | null>();

(see the link for the full code)
I receive this error:
Access to audio at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MYPROJECT.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fcan%20we%20be%20118%20A.wav?alt=media&token=TOKEN' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I've tried things like:
const src = await fetch("theFirebaseUrl", {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    }
}).then((res) => res.url);

And numerous other attempts, but no luck.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Notes

My firebase storage rules are fine, and as I said, it only doesn't work with MediaElementAudioSourceNode.
I have minimal understanding of the web audio API, so I apologize if the solution is in front of my face and I'm not noticing.

Thanks in advance.

I solved this by:

Going to console.cloud.google.com

Creating a cors.json file in the cloud shell.

Setting origin to *.

[
   {
       "origin": ["*"],
       "method": ["GET"],
       "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
       "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]


Then opening the terminal and running
gcloud storage buckets update gs://MY_STORAGE_BUCKET.appspot.com --cors-file=cors.json



